# Auto adjust button size depending on its title size without hardcoding.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to auto adjust  the button size (button should always be at top right corner of the view) depending on its variable title length without hardcoding and auto layout. I have unchecked auto layout for previous screens so I can't enable it for this screen.

Comment: You can enable autolayout for individual screens as well, it won't affect the rest

Comment: Just check it storyboard for that single screen. You said "I unchecked auto layout for previous screens" so do the opposite for this one

Comment: Depends if your "screens" are in a single storyboard or in separate xibs. You can only enable/disable auto layout per file, not per "screen".

Comment: its in single storyboard, so i think its not possible.